# GOOGLE Finance Sheets returns same stock price on different days

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am trying to run a `GoogleFinance` query in GOOGLE Sheets to get the stock price for the same stock. I wish to display the stock price in different rows of column A:

1. On day 1 I will enter the formula in cell A1
2. On day 2 I will enter the formula in cell A2

Here is the basic formula I need to use in A1 and A2:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("F", "price")
```

On Monday Dec 11, 2017, I entered this formula in cell `A1` and it gave 12.54 in cell A1.

On Wedns. Dec 13, 2017, I entered this formula in cell `A2` and it gave 12.68 in cell A2 BUT it also changed cell A1 from 12.54 to 12.68. So, now both `A1` and `A2` shows the same number - 12.68.

I want:

```
A1 = 12.54  // enter formula into this cell on Monday
A2 = 12.68  // enter formula into this cell on Wednesday
```

Is this possible with `GOOGLEFINANCE()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GOOGLEFINANCE` function takes a date or range of dates:

> `GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days],
>   [interval])`
>
> `ticker` - The ticker symbol for the security to consider.
>
> `attribute` - [ OPTIONAL - "price" by default ] - The attribute to fetch
>   about ticker from Google Finance. This is required if a date is
>   specified.
>
> ...
>
> `start_date` - [ OPTIONAL ] - The start date when fetching historical
>   data.
>
> - If `start_date` is specified but `end_date`|`num_days` is not, only the
>     single day's data is returned.
>
> `end_date`|`num_days` - [ OPTIONAL ] - The end date when fetching historical data, or the number of days from `start_date` for which to return data.
>
> `interval` - [ OPTIONAL ] - The frequency of returned data; either "DAILY" or "WEEKLY".
>
> - interval can alternatively be specified as 1 or 7. Other numeric values are disallowed.

Examples:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")
GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,A3)
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en